# Modbus parse negative number

Tags: parsing, modbus

I'm reading data from Satec PMEH130 Plus. When I parse the modbus responses, every number is correct, except from the negative ones, it should return something like -997, but it returns 655xx.. Is there fix for the parsing the negative numbers?

Here's my code:

I send this request to the device:

```
} else if ( testCount == 2 ) {

        buffer[0] = 0x01;   
        buffer[1] = 0x03;  
        buffer[2] = 0x34;  
        buffer[3] = 0x18;   
        buffer[4] = 0x00;   
        buffer[5] = 0x0c;
        buffer[6] = 0xcb;
        buffer[7] = 0xf8;
        lab = 'KVAL1, KVAL2, KVAL3, PFL1, PFL2, PFL3';
```

Device returns modbus string:

```
010318000000000000000000000000fc1dfffffc20fffffc1bffff4fa1
```

This is my modbus parse function:

```
function parseModbus(hexString, type)

{


var LVAL = hexString.substr(4,2);
LVAL = parseInt(LVAL, 16);

var values = hexString.substr(6, (LVAL*2)).match(/.{1,4}/g);

switch(type)
{
    case 2:
        if(values) {
            //console.log(values.length);
            kVAL1 = parseInt(values[0], 16);
            kVAL2 = parseInt(values[2], 16);
            kVAL3 = parseInt(values[4], 16);
            PFL1 = parseInt(values[6], 16);
            PFL2 = parseInt(values[8], 16);
            PFL3 = parseInt(values[10], 16);
        }
    break;
}
```

The incorrect values are in PFL1, PFL2 and PFL3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. You have to substract the value with 65536.

> PFL1 = parseInt(values[6], 16) - 65536;